# How to write a query with count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I have two tables as follows:

```
==================
StudentsClasses  
----------------
ID (Registration ID of the class)
StudentID (ID of student taking class)
ClassID (ID of certain class)
----------------
==================

Students
---------------
ID (ID of student)
Name (Name of student)
GradeLevelID (Grade of student)
---------------
==================
```

And they are joined by StudentsClasses.StudentID and Students.ID.

I am trying to write a query to return the students with the least classes registered. My query is:

```
SELECT Students.Name, COUNT(StudentsClasses.StudentID) AS Expr1
FROM     StudentsClasses INNER JOIN
                  Students ON StudentsClasses.StudentID = Students.ID
GROUP BY StudentsClasses.StudentID, Students.Name
ORDER BY Expr1
```

However, that only returns all the students with at least 1 class in ASC order.

I know the correct answer is 7 students with 0 classes.

How can I modify my query to return only those 7 students with 0 classes.

Comment: An **`INNER JOIN`** will only return rows that exist in both tables. To return rows from `student` for which there are no related rows in `student_class`, you need to use an **`OUTER JOIN`**, with `student` as the driving table. For any rows in `student` that don't have any associated rows in `student_class`, the row from `student` will be returned along with NULL values in place of values from the `student_class` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enlist those students, that have no classes, instead of `INNER JOIN` you should be using `LEFT JOIN` here, to make sure all rows from `students` table are listed, even though there is no rows in `studentclasses` for that particular student.

```
SELECT
 s.name, count(sc.id) AS classes
FROM
 students s
 LEFT JOIN studentsclasses sc ON s.id = sc.studentid
GROUP BY s.name
HAVING count(sc.id) = 0 -- added after comment
ORDER BY count(sc.id);
```

OR another method (for retrieving only students that have 0 classes):

```
SELECT
 s.name
FROM
 students.s
 LEFT JOIN studentsclasses sc ON s.id = sc.studentid
WHERE
 sc.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there any way to limit it to only students with 0 classes?

Comment: Yes, this is done by `HAVING` clause. See my edited answer. Another method for only those can be applied. Simply `JOIN` with classes table and list those names that have no matching rows.

Comment: One more question. I am trying to convert that query into C#, how can I do a left join on C# code? I have a `join c in ent.StudentsClasses on s.ID equals c.StudentID` but that seems like a regular join.

Comment: Google is going to help you with `LEFT JOIN` in `C#`. This is totally different question, which is basically easy to look up on the net. I'm not familiar with `C#` but I've managed to find answers for this even on SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This should limit your results to those students having whatever the minimum number of registered classes is (so if the minimum is currently zero, then zero, if it becomes true that the least number of registrations is 3, then it will use 3, etc.)

```
select      s.name,
            v.classes
from        students s
       join (
                select      s.name,
                            count(sc.id) as classes
                from        students s
                  left join studentsclasses sc
                         on s.id = sc.studentid
                group by    s.name
                order by    count(sc.id)
                limit 1
            ) v
         on s.name = v.name
```

Answer (score -1):

Answers for this question.
 How can I modify my query to return only those 7 students with 0 classes.

```
SELECT
 s.name, count(sc.id) AS classes
FROM
 students s
 LEFT JOIN studentsclasses sc ON s.id = sc.studentid
where (SELECT count(sc.id) FROM
 students s
 LEFT JOIN studentsclasses sc ON s.id = sc.studentid)=0 
GROUP BY s.name
ORDER BY count(sc.id);
```